# Can I own multiple properties?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have just purchased my $400,000 apartment online and the 10 car garage that comes with it but I was wondering if I can own another garage separately or can I only have the one the apartment comes with.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, you cannot own more than one garage. You also can not own more than one apartment or house. And to get even trickier, you cannot have a combination of a house and a separate garage. I hope this was clear and concise.

Comment: These days, you can own up to three propertier at a time; the extra slots unlock a bit later than the initial.

Answer (score 1):

You can only own one at a time. If you bought, say, the $200K apartment then you'd need to raise $300K to buy the $400K.

You get half of the value of your previous apartment/garage when you upgrade.

Not sure about downgrading though.

Comment: Not an answer to the question.  He's not asking if he can have multiple apartments.  He wants to know if he can buy a 2nd garage when he has an apartment that comes with one :)

Comment: @archer Isn't this the answer? "You can only own one at a time."

Comment: @MennoGouw I'd say it's not an answer.  It is if you just read the title, but that's not the question.  The question is very clear to me, and this doesn't answer it.

Comment: The question is if he can own another garage. The short answer is "You can only own one at a time." i do not own the game so i can not verify if that is correct.

Comment: @MennoGouw Yes, the answer I was trying to get is what Archer said.   Sorry if I didn't phrase it right.